# Nginx loads index.html automatically without being instructed to

Tags: nginx

`http://localhost:8001/whatever` loads `/var/www/nginx.html` 
but
`http://localhost:8001` loads `/var/www/index.html`

According to the grep result, there is no uncommented `index.html` mentioned whatsoever.

What I expect is to load `nginx.html` in the second case too.

The only thing I found is when I remove `$uri/` from `try_files` it works as expected.

But basically where is `index.html` configuration? is it nginx's default behavior?

It's good to say that `index.php` is not loaded. I've checked many times and sure about the file.

[image: grep result]

[image: default config file]

Comment: Instead of screenshots, consider copying and pasting your config into your posts instead; text loads faster than screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When otherwise unspecified, the `index` directive has an implied default of `index.html`.  Which is present in your document root. (See the documentation below that I included detailing defaults and such)

If you want to *change* what it serves as its index page, you need to define a new `index` directive, such that you add this to your `/` location block, or apply it globally by just putting it outside the location blocks but still within your server block:

```
index nginx.html;
```

This tells nginx to instead look for a different index file.

The problem you're seeing is because the `/` location block *only* applies if you have the / specified, and because you don't allow `autoindex` and because `/whatever` is your URI and that doesn't exist either as a file or a directory, it falls back to your third option, the `nginx.html` file.  I know this is counter-intuitive, as an empty URI or a `/` URI typically means "Process this per the `location / { }` block, but it's more implied in the world that this takes you to the home or index page of a given website, and that is why the `index` directive exists.

You need to tell the system what to treat as an index file for any configuration.  You can't rely *solely* on `try_files` in your `/` location block, you have to tell it what your index file should be.  I always define this even if the defaults work fine for me.

Note that if you don't define a URI, `try_files` falls back to the `index` directive, so a request to `http://foobarbaz.foo:8510` will reach the nginx server block listening on port 8510 for the server name / `$HOST` request record of `foobarbaz.foo`, with an empty URI, and is technically going to have nginx, internally, try and serve the default `index.html` index page because of your configuration not specifying a different `index` to serve for any type of request.

---

From the [related nginx documentation of the `index` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index):

> > Syntax:    **`index`**`file ...;`
> >     Default: `index index.html;`
> >     Context: `http, server, location`
>
> Defines files that will be used as an index. The file name can contain
>   variables. Files are checked in the specified order. The last element
>   of the list can be a file with an absolute path. Example:
>
> ```
> index index.$geo.html index.0.html /index.html;
> ```
>
> It should be noted that using an index file causes an internal
>   redirect, and the request can be processed in a different location.
>   For example, with the following configuration:
>
> ```
> location = / {
>     index index.html;
> }
>
> location / {
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> ... a “/” request will actually be processed in the second location as
>   “/index.html”.